# Adding a sparkline to a flextable in R

Tags: r, flextable, sparklines

I am trying to use sparkline with a flextable I created for a report.  Unfortunately, I can't get the function tabwid() to work, to convert this into an HTML widget.  It is cited as being part of flextable v0.4.0, but it isn't in v0.5.

I note in the documentation below that the tabwid() function is deprecated:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flextable/versions/0.4.0/topics/tabwid

Is there an equivalent function in v0.5?  If not, is there another way to use the sparkline function within a sparktable?

I noticed a conversation regarding this with the developer of flextable in 2016, and the code described there includes the tabwid() function.   I can't find an alternative and would be grateful for any guidance provided.

https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/1

The code cited in the link above is as follows:

> #devtools::install_github("davidgohel/oxbase")
> #devtools::install_github("davidgohel/flextable")
>
> #devtools::install_github("htmlwidgets/sparkline")
>
> library(dplyr) library(oxbase) library(flextable) library(sparkline)
>
> mtcars %>%   group_by(cyl) %>%   summarise(
> hp = spk_chr(
> hp, type="box",
> chartRangeMin=0, chartRangeMax=max(mtcars$hp)
> ),
> mpg = spk_chr(
> mpg, type="box",
> chartRangeMin=0, chartRangeMax=max(mtcars$mpg)
> )   ) %>%   flextable() %>%   tabwid() %>%   spk_add_deps()

If this isn't possible, has anyone else found a way to add a sparkline into a flextable (e.g., through another package?)?

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

With the dev version on github, you can do the following - these are not interactive graphics:

```
# remotes::install_github("davidgohel/flextable")
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)

# data prep ----
z <- as.data.table(iris)
z <- z[, list(
  Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE),
  z = list(.SD$Sepal.Length)
), by = "Species"]

# flextable ----
ft <- flextable(
  data = z,
  col_keys = c("Species", "Sepal.Length", "box", "density", "line")
) %>%
  compose(j = "box", value = as_paragraph(
    plot_chunk(
      value = z, type = "box",
      border = "white", col = "transparent", 
      width = 1.5, height = .4
    )
  )) %>%
  compose(j = "line", value = as_paragraph(
    plot_chunk(value = z, type = "line", col = "white", 
               width = 1.5, height = .4)
  )) %>%
  compose(j = "density", value = as_paragraph(
    plot_chunk(value = z, type = "dens", col = "white", 
               width = 1.5, height = .4)
  )) %>%
  theme_vader() %>%
  align(j = c("box", "density", "line"), align = "center", part = "all") %>%
  autofit()
ft
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!  Please also accept my VERY long delay in replying.  I will go through this code and see if I can adapt it as well for a table I'm working on.  In my case, I have a table showing the number of new cases of coronavirus in a given locality.  I then would then like to add a sparkling that shows the previous number of new cases by day, to put the current number in context.  I'll look more closely soon! Thank you!